# If W is a subspace of V, show orthogonal complement of W is also a subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra

$W$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$. Show that $W^{\perp}$ is also a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Use the linearity of the dot product and the fact that the zero vector is in $W^\perp$.

Comment: I tried saying that a vector in $W$ is orthogonal to all vectors in $W^\perp$. But I'm not sure how to link this to $V$.

Comment: Just verify one by one the conditions for subspace. (i) Is the $0$-vector in the orthogonal complement? (ii) Is the sum of two vectors in the orthogonal complement also in? (iii) What about a constant times a vector in the orthogonal complement?  Each verification is I think mechanical.

Comment: Yup I figured it out. Thanks for the hints guys.

Comment: A small remark is that the question is not well defined, since the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ does not make any sense for a general vector space. Should have assumed $V$ is an inner product space.

Comment: @DanPetersen I agree with your comment, but unfortunately when I first learned about vector spaces (and it may also be the case for the OP), *everything* was defined over $\mathbb{R}$, and so the inner product was presented as a natural construction on a vector space, instead of giving rise to a different class of algebraic objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to show three things:

1. $W^\perp$ is non-empty.
2. $W^\perp$ is closed under scalar multiplication; that is, if ${\bf
       v}\in W^\perp$, then  $\alpha{\bf v}\in W^\perp$ for all scalars
   $\alpha$.
3. $W^\perp$ is closed under vector addition; that is, if ${\bf
           v_1}\in W^\perp$ and  ${\bf v_2}\in W^\perp$, then  ${\bf v_1}+{\bf
           v}_2\in W^\perp$.

Recall that $\bf v$ is in $W^\perp$ if and only if ${\bf v}\cdot {\bf w}=0$ for all ${\bf w}\in W$.

Towards showing 1) holds, note (and verify) that  the zero vector is in $W^\perp$.

Towards showing  3) holds, suppose that ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ are both  in $W^\perp$.   We have to show that the vector ${\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2$ is in $W^\perp$; so we need to verify that $({\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2)\cdot {\bf w}=0$ for all ${\bf w}\in W$.  Towards this end, use the fact that $({\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2)\cdot {\bf w}=  {\bf v}_1\cdot {\bf w}+{\bf v}_2\cdot {\bf w} $.

I'll leave the verification that 2) holds, and the rest of the verification that 3) holds for you.

Comment: @BrandonCarter yes, thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: What about inverses?